# Conditional check in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pipeline

I have a Dockefile, in which I want to copy certain files based on input environment variable. So far I have tried the following. I am able to verify that my environment variable is passed correctly. During my docker build I get the following error -->> /bin/sh: COPY: not found

```
ARG arg=a
RUN if [ "$arg" = "a" ] ; then \
 echo arg is $arg; \
 COPY test.txt /
else \
 echo arg is $arg; \
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are essentially trying to do here is to have a `COPY` command inside a `RUN` command.

Dockerfiles don't have nested commands.

Moreover, a `RUN` command runs *inside* an intermediate container built from the image. Namely, `ARG arg=a` will create an intermediate image, then docker will spin up a container, and use it to run the `RUN` command, and commit that container as the next intermediate image in the build process.

so `COPY` is not something that can run inside the container, and in fact `RUN` basically runs a shell command inside the container, and `COPY` is not a shell command.

AFAICT dockerfiles don't have any means of doing conditional execution. The best you can do is:

```
COPY test.txt
RUN if [ "$arg" = "a" ] ; then \
 echo arg is $arg; \
else \
 echo arg is $arg; \
 rm -r test.txt \
fi
```

But keep in mind that if test.txt is a 20GB file, the size of your image will still be > 20GB.